# Calling text from API and coredata results in exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling

I am making an app and one of the features is that you take a quiz with some options that ping a web API and show these results. The results pop up on a table view and i have the `self.tableview.reload()` under the `viewdidload()` but I still have to navigate back to the previous view controller and hit the results button again to get the proper results to show. How do i make it so the `tableview` refreshes when it gets called? My second error is the exc_bad_acces (code 1, address: 0x0) and i cannot seem to get it to go away. It happens when the you click on a result in the table view and it takes you to a view controller where a summary of the car is presented. Here is the code used in the file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk4mo.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7X43.png. I can provide more if needed, i hope someone can help!

Comment: The console output will usually show you precisely where your problem is. You should post that code **as text** here and format it accordingly (highlight the code and click curly braces).

Comment: The console pings back the right information and provides the summary. However it seems that displaying the info is where it gets messed up.  Example of of the outputs '
    Summary = "($25,030) This trim offers a Continuously Variable Transmission (CVT) with Paddle Shifters, 18-in. Alloy Wheels, a Leather-Wrapped Steering Wheel, and a Driver's Seat with 10-Way Power Adjustment.\n";'

Answer (score 0):

@adrianB does this help? 
the console output says this

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
var trim : Trims?
@IBOutlet weak var summaryLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func showSummary(sender: AnyObject) {
    summaryLabel.text = trim?.summary  (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address = 0x0)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}`
```